# git: Resolve merge conflicts using strategy

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Scenario:

1. attempt a merge from branch `feature` into `master`
2. witness minor conflicts, e.g. a different version number, that should not be merged

How can you tell git to merge only non-conflicting parts and don't touch conflicting ones, just like when running `git merge -s recursive -Xours feature`?

My current solution is to run `git merge --abort`, followed by the above mentioned strategy-merge. Is there a way to do this without first aborting my merge? I do not want to fire up another tool or work through every conflict one-by-one.

Neither the [git docs on merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) nor this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git) give any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will still have to work through every *file* one by one, but you can use `git merge-file` to achieve what you want.  You may wish to write a script to accomplish the steps below.

When Git stops with a merge conflict, Git leaves *all three* versions of the conflicted file in the index / staging-area.  Let's say, for instance, that the conflicted file is named `README.txt`.  Then because there was a conflict, you have a `README.txt` in your work-tree with conflict markers, but you also have:

- `:1:README.txt`: the `README.txt` from the merge base (the common commit from which both your current commit, and your merge target commit, diverged).
- `:2:README.txt`: the `README.txt` from the `HEAD` or `--ours` commit.
- `:3:README.txt`: the `README.txt` from the `--theirs` commit.

You can extract each of these three files to a temporary file.  The most straightforward way is to use `git show :1:README.txt > README.txt.base`, for instance.  There is a fancier way that is more suitable for scripting—the `git mergetool` command uses this:

```
checkout_staged_file () {
        tmpfile=$(expr \
                "$(git checkout-index --temp --stage="$1" "$2" 2>/dev/null)" \
                : '\([^ ]*\)    ')

        if test $? -eq 0 && test -n "$tmpfile"
        then
                mv -- "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)$tmpfile" "$3"
        else
                >"$3"
        fi
}
```

which it invokes as:

```
    checkout_staged_file 1 "$MERGED" "$BASE"
    checkout_staged_file 2 "$MERGED" "$LOCAL"
    checkout_staged_file 3 "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"
```

In any case, your job is to extract these three files, then run:

```
git merge-file --ours <stage-2-file> <stage-1-file> <stage-3-file>
```

which will leave the merged result, with conflicts resolved in favor of "ours", in `<stage-2-file>`.

Thus, given all the above, if the file is named `README.txt` and you wanted to re-do the merge *of that one file* with the equivalent of `-X ours`, these would work (though the `git show` method does not obey CRLF settings, hence you might want the fancier `git checkout-index` stuff):

```
git show :1:README.txt > README.txt.base
git checkout --ours README.txt
git show :3:README.txt > README.txt.other
git merge-file README.txt README.txt.base README.txt.other
rm README.txt.base README.txt.other
git add README.txt
```

The merge is now complete for `README.txt`.  Repeat these six steps for all other files for which you wish to apply this "override conflicts from `--ours`" rule.

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer! Although, I was hoping for a more straight-forward solution to this seemingly straight-forward problem.

Comment: It would at least be nice for all of this to be wrapped up in a clean and neat script distributed with Git. You could then do `git retry-merge --ours <file>`, and `git-retry-merge` would do all of the above (and perhaps even re-create conflicts with `git checkout -m` if needed).